# Как на С# создать картинку с необходимым текстом?

Tags: c#, rtf, jpeg

Есть динамический текст（или в более сложном варианте-таблица）и нужно сгенерировать .jpg картинку.
Как такоe рeализовать?
Либо как-то из rtf / doc формата гeнeрировать картинку,но только чeрeз C#

Comment: Люблю такие вопросы. Деталей нет, видимо, чтобы не сдерживать фантазию отвечающих.

Comment: Ну, написать текст на битмапе не проблема, но вам придётся форматировать самостоятельно. Вам WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Нужно брать данные списка дел,пример, сварить борщ,купить хлеб....из базы и сформировать список,который потом генерится в картинку,а картинка кладется на рабочий стол

Comment: Wpf лучше.Фактически мне хотелось бы генерить картинку для рабочего стола из данных,но если вариант есть,что б всегда отображалась моя программа,токонечно лучше этот...как раньше виджеты были,но сейчас такого не найду

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о WPF, можно построить таблицу, используя обычные контролы, а затем отрисовать её в изображение:

```
private void RenderControlToFile(UIElement control, string outputFilename) {
    control.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    control.Arrange(new Rect(0d, 0d, control.DesiredSize.Width, control.DesiredSize.Height));

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)control.DesiredSize.Width, (int)control.DesiredSize.Height,
            96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    bitmap.Render(control);

    bitmap.SaveAsPng(outputFilename);
}
```

Если будете использовать эту функцию, не забудьте указать размер у таблицы — здесь `Measure()` вызывается без ограничений, рассчитывая, что контрол сам рассчитает, какого размера он будет.

**UPD:** Если нужно, чтобы приложение было привязано к рабочему столу, можно использовать `SetParent()` из `user32.dll` с хендлом рабочего стола, но с WPF это не сработает. Хотя, возможно, поможет [эта статья](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#hosting_a_wpf_page).